# Why some of the build-in javascript methods are static while some or not?

Tags: javascript

I have have seen that three method of array are static methods are static. `Array.isArray()`, `Array.from()`, `Array.of`. I can understand why they are static methods. Because the variable passed to them can also be something other than array. Same is case with `Number` and `String`.

But I cannot understand that why almost all the methods of `Object` are static. Why `keys`, `entries`,`values` etc are not on `prototype`.

- Is there any advantage of putting them as static method?
- What problems we would have faced if we had `Object.prototype.keys/entries/values...`

Comment: `Object.keys(x)` is very different from `x.keys`, which `x` itself may redefine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with Object methods being on the prototype is that objects in general can have arbitrary key-value pairs. For example, if there was such a thing as `Object.prototype.values`, it could very easily cause confusion when you had an object which you intended to have a `values` property, eg

```
const foo = { values: ['val1', 'val2'] };
```

If `Object.prototype.values` were a thing, to use it here, you would have to do something like

```
const fooValues = Object.prototype.values.call(foo);
```

Better for `values` to be a static method to avoid such name collisions.

If the properties of your objects could be functions as well, it could be even worse, for example:

```
const foo = {
  info: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  values() {
    return this.info;
  }
};
```

Now, if `Object.prototype.values` was a thing, and you saw `foo.values()` in the code, what do you think it would mean? Was the programmer intending to call the `values` property of `foo` (which is what the code would result in), or was the programmer intending to use `Object.prototype.values`? It'd be an easy source of bugs and hard-to-read code.

Same thing for the other Object static methods - they could easily result in name collisions.

Comment: oh, sorry ... I should've looked closely at the foo object :p your example is perfect :p - basically, you want as few "native" properties on the object prototype, since every single thing in javascript is an object :p